# Asterisk (*) in Durandal route

Tags: durandal, single-page-application, sammy.js, durandal-navigation, durandal-2.0

What is the purpose of the asterisk in Durandal routes? Here is an example from [the Docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html):

```
route:'knockout-samples*details'
```

EDIT: Using Durandal 2.0

Comment: Can you specify the Durandal version this question/answer refers to, please? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs you are referencing clearly show what this is for :  )

> Finally, a * denotes a "splat" route. In this case we match anything
>   starting at the position of the *.

Comment: arghhhhhh, face palm, shakes head, "I need a break" :) thanks.